# Unable to acess universe repository

Tags: apt, repository

I'm trying to access all of the repositories but i am unable to change the settings in the software center, command line, or right from the source list. I have a hypothysis that it may be due to unistalled updates but when i run "sudo apt-get install update" it says that it is unable to locate package update. help?

Answer (score 1):

You want this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having some confusion about the syntax of `apt-get`:

To get the most updated **list** of all the software, you do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

For installing packages, you have tell apt-get what to install:

```
sudo apt-get install package
```

You were mixing above commands. To modify your repositories, you could either write in dash "Software Sources" and add/modify/deactivate repositories or editing directly the `sources.list` file:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remember that each time you do `sudo` you are giving yourself god-like powers over your system, use the power with *prudence and responsibility*.